# Integrate over curve specified by Dirac delta functions

Tags: integration, contour-integration, dirac-delta

I need to numerically evaluate an integral of the following form:

$$
I(\omega) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty f(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega)\delta(\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_3-\omega)\delta(\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2+\omega_3^2-\omega^2)d\omega_1d\omega_2d\omega_3
$$

I am assuming this integral converges. The function $f$ and variables $\omega,\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,$ are real and non-negative.

So far I have determined that the delta functions describe the intersection of the plane $\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_3=\omega$ and the sphere $\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2 + \omega_3^2 =\omega^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3_+$, where $\mathbb{R_+}=[0,\infty)$. I believe this intersection can be parameterized by two curves given by
$$
\vec{r}(\omega_3) = [r_1,r_2,r_3]= \left[\frac{1}{2}(\omega_3+\omega)(1+q),\frac{1}{2}(\omega_3+\omega)(1-q),\omega_3\right]
$$
with
$$
q = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2(\omega^2-\omega_3^2)}{(\omega+\omega_3)^2}-1}.
$$
and $\omega_3\in[0,\omega/3]$. Due to the symmetry of $f$, integration over the first of these contours will produce the same value as integration over the second. Let's choose $q$ to be positive. My limited knowledge of calculus has me thinking that
$$
I(\omega) = 2\int_0^{\omega/3} f(r_1,r_2,r_3)|r'(\omega_3)|d\omega_3.
$$
where $|r'(\omega_3)| = \sqrt{r_1'^2+r_2'^2+1}$. This is the expression I would like to integrate numerically.

I am very unsure of the correct way to integrate these delta functions, however, and I can't seem to find a reference for this. Given that my parameterization of the contours is correct, is my expression for $I(\omega)$ valid? I can also envision that the $|r'(\omega_3)|$ might be dropped.

Comment: I wonder if a Monte Carlo approach might be simpler. It's easy enough to generate random points on $\mathbb{R}_+^3$ orthant of the $\omega$-sphere. The other constraint is not so readily dealt with, but as an approximation one can reject points such that $|\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_3-\omega|>\epsilon$. This is not terribly efficient but it may at least be useful for estimation purposes.

Comment: Also, the $\omega$-dependence can be more-or-less removed. First, note that the sphere constraint imposes $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3\leq \omega$. Now let $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)=(\omega x_1,\omega x_2,\omega x_3)$ and $$F(x_1,x_2,x_3|\omega):=f(\omega x_1,\omega x_2,\omega x_3,\omega)=f(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega).$$ The integral becomes $$I(\omega)=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \int_0^1 F(x_1,x_2,x_3|\omega)\delta(x_1+x_2-x_3-1)\delta(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-1)\,dx_1 dx_2d x_3.$$ Note that all of the $\omega$-dependence is now carried entirely by $F$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Monte Carlo is a clever idea, but unfortunately I require a very precise evaluation of the integral along the manifold. I really like the reparametrization with respect to x.